# Как получить доступ к манипулированию файлом

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Моя программа работает с базой данных с помощью EF6. В определенный момент может потребоваться удалить файл базы данных, передать его, либо заменить на другой.

Но в этом случае возникает ошибка *"Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "database.mdf", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."* 
Происходит это только во время работы программы, т.к. после ее завершения через проводник я могу удалять, копировать файл.

Есть ли возможность освободить файл в процессе работы программы? И если есть, то как это реализовать?

Освобождаю контекст после использования. Прилагаю код доступа к бд для наглядности.

```
public static void UpdateObject(object obj)
    {
        if (!IsDatabaseContextCreated)
            return;
        ClientDatabaseContext context = null;
        try
        {
            if (User.DBMSName == "SQLite")
                context = new ClientDatabaseContext(User.ConnectionString, true);
            else
                context = new ClientDatabaseContext(User.ConnectionString);

            if (obj is Organization org)
            {
                var query = context.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(u => u.OrganizationId == org.OrganizationId);
                query.OrganizationName = org.OrganizationName;
            }
            if (obj is Faculty fac)
            {
                var query = context.Faculties.FirstOrDefault(u => u.FacultyId == fac.FacultyId);
                query.FacultyName = fac.FacultyName;
            }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            ErrorManager.ExecuteException(new ErrorManager.NirsException("Ошибка при изменении элемента",
                "База данных", "Работа с базой данных"));
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Возможно, дело в том, что SQL Server не закрывает подключение после обращения к БД?

Comment: Обворачивайте все коннекты, команды и ридеры в `using`. Если не поможет - делайте конекту `Close`. Избегайте длительных операций с СУБД.

Comment: @nick_n_a Приложил фрагмент кода того, как получаю доступ к данным.

Comment: Даже если явно закрыть соединение (`Dispose/Close`) оно, как я понимаю, будет оставаться какое-то время в пуле соединений. И лишь когда из пула будет удалено, тогда можно что-то делать с файлом БД.

Comment: @ AlexanderPetrov можно ли удалить соединение из пула принудительно?

Comment: Это лишь предположение. Думаю, выше я был не прав. Наверняка вы тестируете приложение, запуская из Студии. При этом используется LocalDB. Когда приложение завершается, тогда завершается и процесс LocalDB, после чего файл можно менять/удалять. А если используется полноценная СУБД, процесс которой запущен всегда, то нужно будет сделать DETACH. В общем, нужно экспериментировать.

Comment: @Damian https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Я в строке подключения добавил pooling=false; как считаете, сильно просядет производительность? Я просто не совсем силен в этом, но учеба требует. Но решение работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Connection.Close();
context.Database.Connection.Close();
context.Dispose();
```